# IEEE 829 test plan documentation standard contains all of the following except

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I have found in muck test the following question:

IEEE 829 test plan documentation standard contains all of the following except:
a) test items
b) test deliverables
c) test tasks
d) test environment
e) test specification

According to the website, the right answer is the option e). However, if you have a look of the IEEE 829 test plan documentation, one of the Sections to be included is:
-Test deliverables : The artifacts created by the testing team that will be delivered as per this plan. Examples include - **test specifications (design, case and procedure)**, output from tools, test reports, etc.

It looks a bit confusing. Is it a wrong question ? . When they ask about **"test specification"** without a **"s"** at the end, are they referring to another topic ?

Answer (score 0):

To understand why the option e) is the right answer, we need to understand what is the **Question Format** in the actual exam. In a book, I found the following explanation:

"The correct answer is called the key option. Incorrect or inferior choices are called distracters. Within the context of a specific question, a distracter may be "incorrect" simple because it is inferior to the key option. In other cases, a distracter may also be a true statement but an incorrect response option if associated with the current question."

In other words we are looking for the best option. In this particular question, we can say "except" the option **e)  test specification**  because the option **b) test deliverables** already includes the **tests specifications**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the correct answer is "
Except Test specification " as below is the format for test plan documentation:

1. Test Plan Identifier
2. References
3. Introduction
4. Test Items
5. Software Risk Issues
6. Features to be Tested
7. Features not to be Tested
8. Approach
9. Item Pass/Fail Criteria
10. Approvals
11. Test Deliverables
12. Remaining Test Tasks
13. Glossary
14. Staffing and Training Needs
15. Responsibilities
16. Suspension Criteria and Resumption Requirements
17. Planning Risks and Contingencies
18. Schedule
19. Environmental Needs

Comment: The item 11 refers to this: "Test deliverables : The artifacts created by the testing team that will be delivered as per this plan. Examples include - test specifications (design, case and procedure), output from tools, test reports, etc." As you can see **Test specifications** appears within the description of your item 11, which is confusing and it is the reason for my question.